# what is wrong with Spring mvc annotation based controller RequestMappingHandlerMapping?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am porting one of my applications from the Spring tool suit IDE to pure Eclipse Java EE IDE.
In this process, I'm renaming some packages and changed to Maven based. Then all the controllers don't work anymore.

I think the annotation controller discovery seems broken. no mapping url is registared with Spring.

Does anyone knows what the problem is?

I collect the old log from my STS(working), it works and likes like

```
> 2013-04-21 22:43:05,622 [Thread-1] DEBUG
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -
> Finished creating instance of bean
> 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#2'
> 2013-04-21 22:43:05,623 [Thread-1] DEBUG
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
> - Looking for request mappings in application context: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'HelloSpringroo2-servlet': startup
> date [Sun Apr 21 22:43:05 EDT 2013]; parent: Root
> WebApplicationContext 2013-04-21 22:43:05,653 [Thread-1] INFO 
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
> - Mapped "{[/account/create],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}"
> onto public java.lang.String
> com.hellospringroo.controllers.AccountController.createAccountActionDisplay(org.springframework.ui.Model)
> 2013-04-21 22:43:05,653 [Thread-1] INFO 
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
> - Mapped "{[/account/view/{account_Id}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}"
> onto public java.lang.String
> com.hellospringroo.controllers.AccountController.viewAccountActionDisplay(int,org.springframework.ui.Model)
> throws java.lang.Exception
```

Then I collect the log from Eclipse(Problem one)

```
> 2013-04-21 22:48:04,900 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet
> with name 'Education' processing GET request for [/Education/]
> 2013-04-21 22:48:04,901 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
> - Looking up handler method for path / 2013-04-21 22:48:04,901 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
> - Did not find handler method for [/] 2013-04-21 22:48:04,904 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG
> org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping -
> Mapping [/] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler
> [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController@54bbb2d0]
> and 1 interceptor 2013-04-21 22:48:04,905 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified
> value for [/Education/] is: -1 2013-04-21 22:48:04,914
> [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -
> Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'index'
```

Comment: If you renamed your packages, you have to go and rename them in your component-scans as well.

Comment: Can you check your classpath to see whether all the class files are copied to the expected packages

Comment: yes i inspect the war file. the class file are there. also match context:component-scan base-package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="old.package.name" />
```

should now be

```
<context:component-scan base-package="new.package.name" />
```

Comment: that's what i have done. and i verify the packge name is right

Comment: context:component-scan base-package for my JPA works fine. just for controllers doesnt work

Comment: @Grey Do you have `mvc:annotation-driven`?

Comment: also - when your application boots, do you see the mapping in the log?

Comment: yes. i have annottation driven. and it works for JPA annotations for Entity creation. No it the mapping is not shown in boots

Comment: I finally found the issue. I changed <context:component-scan base-package="old.package.name" /> for my applicationContext.xml but leave the webmvc-config.xml. Consequently, JPA entinity, services are scaned ok except controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you by any chance changed the version of Spring jars from 3.0 to 3.2 or from 3.2.M1 from 3.2.2 etc?

I had similar problem (not exact), but this is what worked for me.

Old version had  `@Controller("\abc")` with handler Method `@RequestMapping("\pqr")`. the urls which were handled were `\abc\pqr`

with new version that did not worked I had to change it to 
`@Controller @RequestMapping ("\abc")` and then handler method mapping same as above.
Or use complete url mappings on handler method instead of at controller level for example `@RequestMapping("\abc\pqr")` on method level.